# ansible perform additional action only if host rebooted

Tags: linux, ansible

I've got a playbook that will get run on hosts on an as-needed basis. I'm running into a problem and I haven't been able to find the answer myself.

We have hosts that are running an application we're building, and there are a few servers where updates are not done automatically. The goal is to do these updates when needed via ansible. The problem is this: **if** during the update process the host is rebooted, there are additional steps that need to be taken. However, if the host did **not** reboot, these steps need to be omitted.

Here's roughly what the yml file looks like:

```
---
- name: run updates on demand
  hosts: static-hosts
  roles:
    - update_system
    - update_component1
    - update_component2
```

*Here I need some kind of check. If the steps above caused the host to reboot, do the following. If it did not reboot, simply stop here.*

```
    - rebuild_component1
    - rebuild_component2
```

Any suggestions? I may be going about this all wrong, if that's the case I'd appreciate if I get pointed in the right direction. Thanks!

---

Thought of possible solution, however not yet tested. Since it's ansible that does the reboot (which wasn't listed in my original yml file), one way this might be doable is with the following yml:

```
---
- name: run updates on demand
  hosts: static-hosts
  roles:
    - update_system
    - update_component1
    - update_component2
  register: updated

- name: reboot
  shell: shutdown -r now
  when: updated.changed

- name: wait for SSH
  (usual "wait for ssh block")

- name: rebuild if rebooted
  roles:
    - rebuild_component1
    - rebuild_component2
  when: updated.changed
```

What I'm not sure about is if updated.changed really only triggers the reboot (and therefore the rebuild) if the updates require it.

Comment: By the way I realize that the idea of only having to rebuild the app after an update if the host reboots sounds weird, but that is in fact the case. It only requires rebuilding if the host gets a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

My "possible solution" listed above works.

Answer (score -1):

You could register the uptime of the host via command and depend on this. Maybe not the perfect solution, but i think this could work.

```
- command: uptime
  register: uptime
```

Comment: I thought of using something like that but I think I might have found a more elegant solution by using register/when in ansible since it does the reboot itself. Updating question now.

Comment: I think your solution looks good. The wait for ssl should also be easy: (From [Docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/wait_for_module.html#examples))

`# wait 300 seconds for port 22 to become open and contain "OpenSSH", don't assume the inventory_hostname is resolvable
# and don't start checking for 10 seconds
- local_action: wait_for port=22 host="{{ ansible_ssh_host | default(inventory_hostname) }}" search_regex=OpenSSH delay=10
`